# K8s tls port forvard

Tags: kubernetes, portforwarding, gitea

I have a Kubernetes cluster where I'm trying to deploy a Gitea application that listens on port :22 in container for tls SSH, but I need to expose port :222 externally for users. What is the way to achieve this port forwarding?

The goal is to allow users to use the command 'git clone ssh://git@domain-name:222/'."

I try this in my deployment:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gitea-ssh
  namespace: develop
  labels:
    app: gitea-ssh
spec:
  selector:
    app: gitea
  ports:
    - name: gitea-ssh
      port: 222
      #targetPort: 22
  type: ClusterIP


---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: ingressroutetcp.crd
  namespace: develop
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - ssh
  routes:
    - match: HostSNI(`*`)
      services:
        - name: gitea-ssh
          port: 22
```